# Haxe server-client exchange on all platforms

Tags: sockets, websocket, client, server, haxe

I'm developing client-server application on haxe. I want client side to be compiled to javascript from haxe, but there is a big chance, that other languages will be also needed. I cannot find universal way of doing it. Though, I can make it with websockets, when it comes to jabascript, and on haxe Sockets, in every other language.

So question is: is there a way to make a client-server application on haxe, without branching code for different platforms?

Comment: Is there any chance that non-Haxe clients/servers will become part of the solution later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is Haxe Remoting, which is part of the Standard Library

> *Haxe remoting is a way to communicate between different platforms. With Haxe remoting, applications can transmit data transparently, send data and call methods between server and client side.*
>
> **relevant sources:**
>   http://haxe.org/manual/std-remoting.html
>   http://api.haxe.org/haxe/remoting/

As side note, if you are looking into creating a actual website with client/server in one project you might want to look into http://www.ufront.net

Comment: I don't understand how to test this example: http://haxe.org/manual/std-remoting-connection.html . I compiled client example to js, but how to launch server properly?

Comment: Did you also created a haxe project with the server code? Both should work together afaik.

Comment: Yes, I launched it, and i get an error in browser "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:2000/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access"

Comment: Oh, I see there is a comment about javascript and cors. Okay, I'll try with server. Thank you.